# c# create a sql query with null values

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I do this in my **sql managment studio**

```
SELECT * FROM SMSMessage WHERE respondCode IS NULL
```

and I **got results**

I want to do that query from C#

I tried this:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM SMSMessage WHERE respondCode IS @respondCode";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Utilities.getConnectionString());
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@respondCode", DBNull.Value);
```

I got this exxception :

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '@respondCode'.
```

why please?

I also tried

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM SMSMessage WHERE respondCode IS NULL";
```

and I got empty results.

#### Uupdate

```
string query = @"SELECT *
    FROM SMSMessage
    WHERE (respondCode = @respondCode)
       OR (@respondCode IS NULL AND respondCode IS NULL)";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Utilities.getConnectionString());
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@respondCode", DBNull.Value);
            con.Open();
            using (con)
            {
                DataTable results = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                sda.Fill(results);
```

Comment: "I also tried `string query = "SELECT * FROM SMSMessage WHERE respondCode IS NULL";"` and got empty results. Sounds like you are connecting to a different instance/database than the one you are connecting to in SSMS then.

Comment: no no the same one, i just have one instance,

Comment: Then, how did you concluded that you are getting empty result set?

Comment: Could also be table in different schema.

Comment: Also, might be the debugger behavior.
Did you try to execute 2 lines past `sda.Fill(results);` and see if you have positive row count?

Comment: @Dusan yes i did , and actually i am making loop on the rows, and the number of rows is always zero :(

Comment: @Dusan you can access my laptop if you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `NULL` values cannot be compared, the `NULL = NULL` evaluates to unknown, your query needs to be:

```
SELECT * FROM SMSMessage 
WHERE (respondCode = @respondCode) OR
      (respondCode IS NULL AND @respondCode IS NULL)
```

Comment: help pleaes,  i am getting empty results, though there are results in the datagase

Comment: Are you sure you are pointing to the same database? Check your connection string.

Comment: yes the same database, i am using datatabel to fill the data and the number of rows = 0

Comment: I will try to change the query to check if i get results and update you

Comment: i am getting empty values in all queries :( :( i will keep checking

Comment: i accepted your answer, thanks , i updated my questions, with the code i am using, could you check please why i am geetting empty result? i am using the same database really, i just have one sql instance

Answer (score 0):

One way of writing this query to behave as you desire would be

```
SELECT *
FROM   SMSMessage
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT respondCode
               INTERSECT
               SELECT @respondCode)
```